# How to retrive data from database in the form of grid in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, twitter-bootstrap

I want to retrieve data from database in the form of grid for this i use bootstrap columns but data will be retrieve in the form of list by default in ruby on rails 5.This is my view code`

```
<div class="row">
            <div class=col-md-3>
                <% unless @fridges.blank? %>
                <% @fridges.each do |fridge| %>
                <div class="card card-cascade narrower">
                    <div class="view overlay hm-white-slight">
 <%= image_tag(fridge.image.url(:medium), :alt => "Fridge Item", :class => "img-fluid")%>
                        <a>
                            <div class="mask waves-effect waves-light"></div>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="card-block text-center">
                        <a href class=text-muted>
                            <h5><%= fridge.Amount %></h5>
                        </a>
                        <h4 class=card-title>
                            <strong>
                               <%= link_to fridge.Name, fridge_path(fridge) %>
                            </strong>
                        </h4>
                        <div class=card-footer>
                            <span class=left><%= fridge.Amount %></span>
                            <span class=right>
                                <%= truncate(fridge.Quantity) %>
                            </span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <% end %>
    </div>`
```

Table name = fridges, [here is the screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nYVpg.png) that i want to display data. All the styles is properly working but only issue is data is shown in list form [check here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6nmrT.png). Please help me Thanks.

Comment: edit your question

Comment: Please read "[ask]" and "[mcve]" and their linked pages. Don't use links to images. Links rot then break making the question difficult to understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your "col-md-3" is missing ", and you have to put the column size inside the loop each, here is your revision that you can try

```
<div class="row">
  <% unless @fridges.blank? %>
    <% @fridges.each do |fridge| %>
      <div class="col-md-3">
        <div class="card card-cascade narrower">
            <div class="view overlay hm-white-slight">
              <%= image_tag(fridge.image.url(:medium), :alt => "Fridge Item", :class => "img-fluid")%>
                <a>
                    <div class="mask waves-effect waves-light"></div>
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="card-block text-center">
                <a href class=text-muted>
                    <h5><%= fridge.Amount %></h5>
                </a>
                <h4 class=card-title>
                    <strong>
                       <%= link_to fridge.Name, fridge_path(fridge) %>
                    </strong>
                </h4>
                <div class=card-footer>
                    <span class=left><%= fridge.Amount %></span>
                    <span class=right>
                        <%= truncate(fridge.Quantity) %>
                    </span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
</div>
```